# Merge line shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, line, autocad

I've imported some of line shapefiles drawn in AutoCAD, so now I have one shapefile with multiple features (one feature is one line drawn in AutoCAD).
How can I merge all of these features into one single feature?

Comment: What I know that Polyline objects should be connected together if they are one feature. Can you explain the reason for doing that or show a screenshot so we can give other suggestions ?

Comment: @Shiko Features are connected and they create one line that is my shapefile, I'm just wondering how can I do it, there is no special reason for doing it, simply I dont want to have 27 features in one shapefile, I want to merge them so I can have one.

Comment: Another question, how can I merge specific features in one shapefile, for example, to merge only features that are spatialy in specific (polygone) feature of another shapefile?

Comment: I suggest to import them as cad layers, coz autocad have not so much operation in outside layers like (shp,mdb,dbf...)

Comment: You can use join lines in Autocad as in this link https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-19D69F56-9A1C-4277-AE9D-5C15DF27986F-htm.html

Answer (score 1):

To merge lines and polylines using Autocad, use **Join** feature as in below link:

1. Click Home tab > Modify panel > Edit Polyline.  Find [image]
2. Select a polyline,spline, line, or arc to edit. If you selected a spline, line, or
   arc, press Enter to convert the selected object into a polyline.
3. Enter j (Join). Select one or more polylines, splines, lines, or
   arcs that are located end to end.
4. Press Enter to end the command.

**Reference:**
**https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-19D69F56-9A1C-4277-AE9D-5C15DF27986F-htm.html**